# Zoom level plugins for android and i phone

Tags: android, iphone, plugins, jquery-plugins

i need a plugin that can help me to zoom my project pages on android and iphone.The user should be able to handle the zoom level.i mean he could zoom in and zoom out the image as much he wants to.It will be a great help.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this library to pinch zoom the image
https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/example/touch/TouchImageView.java